# Unix script for checking logs for last 10 days

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, teradata

I have a log table which is maintained for a single day and the data from the table is only present for one day.However, the logs for it is present in the unix directory.

My requirement is to check the logs for the last 10 days and find me the count of records got loaded.

In the log file the pattern is something like this( fastload log of teradata).

```
**** 13:16:49 END LOADING COMPLETE

     Total Records Read              =  443303
     Total Error Table 1             =  0  ---- Table has been dropped
     Total Error Table 2             =  0  ---- Table has been dropped
     Total Inserts Applied           =  443303
     Total Duplicate Rows            =  0
```

I want to the script to be parametrized( parameter will be stage table name) which find the records inserted into table and error tables for the last 10 days.

Is this possible? Can anyone help me build the unix script for this?

There are many logs in the logs directory. what if a want to check only for the below:

```
    bash-3.2$ ls -ltr 2018041*S_EVT_ACT_FLD*
-rw-rw----+  1 edwops   abgrp      52610 Apr 10 17:37 20180410173658_S_EVT_ACT_FLD.log
-rw-rw----+  1 edwops   abgrp      52576 Apr 11 18:12 20180411181205_S_EVT_ACT_FLD.log
-rw-rw----+  1 edwops   abgrp      52646 Apr 13 18:04 20180413180422_S_EVT_ACT_FLD.log
-rw-rw----+  1 edwops   abgrp      52539 Apr 14 16:16 20180414161603_S_EVT_ACT_FLD.log
-rw-rw----+  1 edwops   abgrp      52538 Apr 15 14:15 20180415141523_S_EVT_ACT_FLD.log
-rw-rw----+  1 edwops   abgrp      52576 Apr 16 15:38 20180416153808_S_EVT_ACT_FLD.log
```

Thanks.

Comment: *log table which is maintained for a single day* Is this log table Teradata's QueryLog? Then it's daliy offloaded to a history database, i.e.   all the info should be still on the system.

Comment: Dear Dnoeth,
No, this is the fload log for each daily run.

Comment: If you need more than 1 day you simply shouldn't delete, can't be a large amount of data :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find . -ctime -10 -type f -print|xargs awk -F= '/Total Records Read/ {print $2}'|paste -sd+| bc
```

`find . -ctime -10 -type f -print`   get the filenames of files 10 days or younger in current working directory.  To run on a different directory replace `.` with the path

`awk -F= '/Total Records Read/ {print $2}'`  using = as a field seperator filter out the second half of any line containing the key phrase
*Total Records Read*

`paste -sd+` add a plus sign

`bc` evaluate the stream of numbers and operators into a single answer

Comment: Thanks Vorsprung
What if i want to check for a particular file like Below:
bash-3.2$ ls -ltr 2018041*S_EVT_ACT_FLD*
-rw-rw----+  1 edwops   abgrp      52610 Apr 10 17:37 20180410173658_S_EVT_ACT_FLD.log
-rw-rw----+  1 edwops   abgrp      52576 Apr 11 18:12 20180411181205_S_EVT_ACT_FLD.log

Comment: Also getting error :xargs: Child killed with signal 13

Comment: simplified slightly, try that

Comment: It's executing till the awk part. What's the use of paste -sd+?

Comment: As I explained above (sorry I wasn't clear) the ``paste -sd+`` command adds a plus sign to the inputs.  It also joins individual lines together.  I suggest you run ``seq 1 9`` and then ``seq 1 9 | paste -sd+`` to demonstrate this

Answer (score 0):

I could not use find. because the system is Solaris, find doesn't have maxdepth future. I use case to create a FILTER2 and use it to

```
ls -l --time-style=long-iso FOLDER | grep -E $FILTER.
```

but I know it's not a good way.

```
LOCAL_DAY=`date "+%d"`
LOCAL_MONTH=`date "+%Y-%m"`
LASTTENDAYE_MONTH=`date --date='10 days ago' "+%Y-%m"`

case $LOCAL_DAY in 
    0*)
       FILTER2="$LASTTENDAY_MONTH-[2-3][0-9]|$LOCAL_MONTH";;
    1*)
       FILTER2="$LOCAL_MONTH-0[0-9]|$LOCAL_MONTH-1[0-9]";;
    2*)
       FILTER2="$LOCAL_MONTH-1[0-9]|$LOCAL_MONTH-2[0-9]";;
esac
```